# Undefined class 'MessageHandlerInterface'

Tags: php, symfony5, symfony-messenger

I am trying to implement `symfony/messenger` to my current `Symfony 5.4` project. I have installed

```
composer require messenger
```

Next, I try to create a handler

```
class SmsNotificationHandler implements MessageHandlerInterface
{
    public function __invoke(SmsNotification $message)
    {
    }
}
```

For some reason `MessageHandlerInterface` is not available.

```
Undefined class 'MessageHandlerInterface'
```

Can anybody please assist me here.

Comment: Maybe a cache story...possible to see your entire class code?

Comment: No its not cache issue. But strangely now it works.